# Problems when using strtok function

Tags: c++

Good morning to everybody, :)

I have writen a code in C++ that reads information from a txt file. It takes the information in the first row saving it in a string and then I want to work with this info. I want to read this string and when it finds a "|" character it must jump to a new line. Its something quite easy but I'm having problems when executing and I've been trying to find the problem for hours and I haven't suceed. :( I attached the code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream ifs( "C:\\a\\text.txt" );
    string temp;

    getline( ifs, temp ); 
    cout<<temp<<endl;

    string * pch;
    pch = strtok (temp,"|");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "|");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which kind of problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I have problems when compiling. In the second part of the program, when using strok function it seems I have some mistakes: In line 24: Cannot convert `std::string' to `char*' for argument `1' to `char* strtok(char*, const char*)' and in line 29 cannot convert `char*' to `std::string*' in assignment, but I don't really understand this problem, and don't know how to solvent it... :S

Comment: Probably that it doesn't compile, since he is using std::string with a function that's made for `char*`

Comment: So how could I rewrite my code so that I didn't have any problem when compiling?

Comment: Please don't learn from tutorials/books that tell you to put `system("pause")` at the end of your main function.

Comment: Why not use STL algorithms rather than using strtok, when using string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strtok works with char*, not string***. That's probably why you're experiencing issues.

Since you're implementing this with c++, I suggest you use the string functions instead of strtok:

```
int main()
{

    ifstream ifs( "C:\\a\\text.txt" );
    string temp;

    getline( ifs, temp ); 
    cout<<temp<<endl;

    size_t tokenPos = temp.find("|");   

    while (tokenPos != string::npos)
    {
        cout << temp.substr(0, tokenPos) << endl;
        temp.erase(0, tokenPos+1);
        tokenPos = temp.find("|");  
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

To store your text in the values you described in your comment, you'd do the following:

```
int main() 
{ 
    ifstream ifs( "C:\\a\\text.txt" ); 

    int id; 
    int type; 
    int columns; 
    string temp; 

    getline( ifs, temp ); 
    cout<<temp<<endl; 

    size_t tokenPos = temp.find("|");
    while (tokenPos != string::npos) 
    { 
        int i=0; 
        tokenPos = temp.find("|"); 
        cout << temp.substr(0, tokenPos) << endl; 

        if(i==0)
        { 
            id = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        }
        else if(i==1) 
        { 
            type = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        } 
        else if(i==2) 
        { 
            columns = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        } 

        ++i; 
        temp.erase(0, tokenPos+1); 
    } 

    cout << "ID: " << id << ", Type: " << type << ", Columns: " << columns << endl; 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Working with your idea now I have a problem. Continuing with my code, now I want to identify and assign to a variable every different element read from my file and separated with "|". But when defining it as temp.substr(0, tokenPos) I have problems when compiling. I attached my code:

Comment: #include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream ifs( "C:\\a\\text.txt" );
  int id;
  int type;
  int columns;
  
   string temp;

   getline( ifs, temp ); 
   cout<<temp<<endl;

   size_t tokenPos = temp.find("|");
   
   while (tokenPos != string::npos)
   {
         int i=0;
         tokenPos = temp.find("|");   
         cout << temp.substr(0, tokenPos) << endl;
         temp.erase(0, tokenPos+1);


         if(i=0)
         {
                id=temp.substr(0, tokenPos);

         }

Comment: if(i=1)
         {
                type=temp.substr(0, tokenPos);
         }

         if(i=2)
         {
                columns=temp.substr(0, tokenPos);
         }
         i++;
   }
   
   cout<<id;
   cout<<type;
   cout<<columns;

system("pause");
return 0;

}

Comment: You can't assign strings straight to ints. If you want the int from the string, use type = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); and the same for columns. Also, comparason operator is ==, so use if(i==1), instead of if(i=1). Don't forget to do ++i; before the end of the while loop.

Comment: Greaaaaaat!!! It works perfectly!! Thanks again!! People like you really motivates me to keep on working with programming! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to tokenize a std::string.  Here is one way; I chose this primarily because it's simple and self-contained:

```
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  ifstream ifs("C:/a/text.txt");
  vector<string> bits;  // if you want to save to process
  for (string temp; getline(ifs, temp, '|');) {
    bits.push_back(temp);
    cout << temp << '\n';  // if you want to output each as processed
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find some ways to do that in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string). As you use C++, it is usually not the way to resort to C style functions. Concerning your code, try to give us the exact error. It helps ...

I see lots of problems in your code. Here is a working example from [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) :

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As stated in the doc, you need to give strtok a non-const c-string as it will modify it in order to process tokens.

my2c

Comment: I've attached the mistakes in a previous comment. So how would I have to rewrite my code so that it works properly??

Comment: @thomas: I have added an example. It should make the trick :) But prefer the STL way of doing it or boost way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
  pch = strtok (temp,"|");
```

to

```
  pch = strtok (temp.c_str(),"|");
```

strtok takes char* (c-style string) not ::std::string (c++ string).

**UPDATE2**
My mistake. I haven't used strtok for so long.
Ok.
Try this one:

```
char* s = new char[temp.size() + 1];
memcpy(s, temp.c_str(), temp.size() + 1);  // copy c-style string with '\0' at the end
const char* pch = strtok(s, "|");
...
delete[] s;
```

Comment: temp.c_str() is char const*, not char*.

Comment: It makes the following mistake: invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char*'

Comment: the update still don't work, of course, since you are not copying temp into s.

Comment: The code in the update allocates one too few chars, doesn't copy the data from temp into the array, and you should avoid manual resource release (e.g. the delete) in C++.

Comment: I always used ::std::vector in release, but author doesn't really understand difference of c-style strings and ::std::string, so i posted the simpliest decision. Yeah, i've forgotten memcpy, but found this mistake right after post and edited it.

Comment: my bad, i should go sleep now. I've forgotted about null-terminator too. finally edited the code.

Comment: The simplest decision is not always the best. Especially when the OP appears to be learning C++ and so should be making full use of the std:: libraries instead of messing around with heap memory and C string functions.